# Как изменить библиотеки в проекте в SVN в intellij Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, svn, jar

Я удалила из проекта несколько старых и добавила в проект несколько новых библиотек в папку lib и закоммитила изменения. На первый взгляд, изменения библиотек произошли успешно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в `Project Structure` видны старые библиотеки (выделены красным цветом), а новых библиотек нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно нужно коммитить изменения библиотек в `SVN` в `Intellij Idea`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вон та закладка, на втором скриншоте. Выделяете старые библиотеки и нажимаете красный минус в шапке окна.

Потом жмете зеленый плюс и выбираете нужные новые библиотеки.

Заливать библиотеки, используемые в проекте, в систему контроля версий - моветон.
Заливайте в репозиторий файл с описанием зависимостей(скорее всего у вас он лежит в корне проекта и имеет расширение .iml)

Comment: я делала так, но библиотеки добавились только в локальный проект, а в SVN никаких изменений не произошло, при скачивании проекта из SVN  проблема не исчезла

Comment: Ну вообще, насколько я понимаю, библиотеки в SVN запихивать - дурной тон. Но если очень хочется, то можно пойти сначала вашим путем - физически их заменить, а потом в настройках проекта поменять для текущего проекта.

Comment: @rjhdby собранные библиотеки добавлять в любую система контроля версий может быть действительно не очень правильно, но иногда требуется. SVN с этим должен справляться без проблем.